# Move quickly between pages in Safari on iOS7?

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, multi-touch

I know you can swipe from the screen edges to move forward and back in your history. I am looking for a quick way to go between the open web pages on my iPhone (without all the tapping required to bring up the overlay buttons, then the page view, then scroll to another page).

It would be great if there is a way to use multi-finger swipes to switch between open pages (~tabs), like <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>}</kbd> on OSX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Safari does not have a feature like the one you're describing. However, Chrome for iOS has this functionality by default.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do what you're asking for.

Swipe gestures have been introduced only to navigate the page history (back or forward).